# requester is not available to add as a recipient in email alert

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a object donation request. Sales user should create a donation request so i have granted read,edit,create & view all object permission to all sales profiles. Now when the donation request is accepted or rejected i want to send a notification mail to requested user that their request is accepted or rejected. But when i am adding the email alert to my workflow rule in recipients i can't see related user : requester. What is the issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have "requester" look up in your object?

Comment: No i have only one lookup to user and that is approver in my donation request object.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lookup field for  "Requester" field in your object to use it in the Email Alert through the related user option!

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please vote and accept the answer! This might help people if they come across a similar issue!  :-)